# how did I get onscreen keypad support in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I want onscreen keypad support to type numbers only (numeric keypad) in TextField. So far I get the default keypad with both alphabets and numbers. Is there any method available to show onscreen numeric keypad instead of default one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `myTextField.setConstraint(TextArea.NUMERIC);`

You also have other constraint options such as password, decimal, url, email etc.